# How to loop through txt file sentence by sentence?

Tags: r

Loading in the txt file:

```
subtitle <- readLines('subtitle.txt')
```

Now I would like to loop through the text sentence by sentence such as:

```
first_sentece <- subtitle[1]
```

How can I do so in R?

**Sample text:**

> I think that’s not true. I think it’s unfortunate. I think myself and everybody who works on these movies loves cinema, loves movies, loves going to the movies, loves to watch a communal experience in a movie theater full of people. And we’ve been very lucky that our movie theaters are often full of people when our movies play, and that’s a very special thing.

Comment: What defines the start/end of a sentence?  Can you add some sample data to your question?

Comment: And another thing, why do you keep replace "first_sentece" with subtitle.. Maybe you want to elaborate on what you would like to do with the lines in subtitle.txt?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added sample data. Start and end is defined by a dot ".".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a hint in the right direction, `strsplit` might be helpful here:

```
x <- "I think that’s not true. I think it’s unfortunate. I think myself and everybody who works on these movies loves cinema, loves movies, loves going to the movies, loves to watch a communal experience in a movie theater full of people. And we’ve been very lucky that our movie theaters are often full of people when our movies play, and that’s a very special thing."
strsplit(x, "\\.\\s*")[[1]]
```

This outputs:

```
[1] "I think that’s not true"                                                                                                                                                             
[2] "I think it’s unfortunate"                                                                                                                                                            
[3] "I think myself and everybody who works on these movies loves cinema, loves movies, loves going to the movies, loves to watch a communal experience in a movie theater full of people"
[4] "And we’ve been very lucky that our movie theaters are often full of people when our movies play, and that’s a very special thing"
```

This answer makes the assumption that full stop (`.`) would always mean the end of sentence.  This of course would not be true if, for example, a given sentence had an acronym or initial in it, e.g. `J.J. Abrams makes good movies`.